# TestContainer SQS Java And Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers

You need to test a class that will be an SQS listener using container testing.

But I'm encountering an error that I can't resolve, I've tried several approaches but it hasn't resolved it, can anyone give a contribution as to what the problem is?

I added the dependency aws-java-sdk-sts because the error was `com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path`

And now after inserting this dependency I started to have this new error that I describe below

**Maven dependency**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-aws-messaging.version}</version>
</dependency>
        
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
        

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
        
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
    <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>localstack</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.604</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Test**

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
public class SQSListenerTest {

    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Autowired
    private QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate;

    @Container
    public static LocalStackContainer localStackContainer = new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:2.0"))
            .withServices(SQS)
            .withEnv("HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL", "localhost");

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void overrideConfiguration(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("sqs.queue.name", () -> QUEUE_NAME);
        registry.add("spring.cloud.aws.region.static", () -> localStackContainer.getRegion());
        registry.add("spring.cloud.aws.credentials.access-key", () -> localStackContainer.getAccessKey());
        registry.add("spring.cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key", () -> localStackContainer.getSecretKey());
        registry.add("spring.cloud.aws.sqs.endpoint", () -> localStackContainer.getEndpointOverride(SQS).toString());
    }

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        localStackContainer.execInContainer("awslocal", "sqs", "create-queue", "--queue-name", QUEUE_NAME);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleWebhook() {
        queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(QUEUE_NAME, "Test message");
    }
}
```

**Erro**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: You must specify a value for roleArn and roleSessionName

    at com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider$Builder.<init>(STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.java:390)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.internal.STSProfileCredentialsService.getAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider(STSProfileCredentialsService.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.internal.securitytoken.STSProfileCredentialsServiceProvider.getProfileCredentialsProvider(STSProfileCredentialsServiceProvider.java:39)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.internal.securitytoken.STSProfileCredentialsServiceProvider.getCredentials(STSProfileCredentialsServiceProvider.java:71)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1269)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:845)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:794)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2207)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2174)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2163)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeGetQueueUrl(AmazonSQSClient.java:1201)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.getQueueUrl(AmazonSQSClient.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.support.destination.DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver.resolveDestination(DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver.java:94)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.support.destination.DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver.resolveDestination(DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver.java:38)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.CachingDestinationResolverProxy.resolveDestination(CachingDestinationResolverProxy.java:92)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.support.AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.resolveMessageChannelByLogicalName(AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.support.AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.java:80)
    at com.demo.message.listener.SQSListenerTest.testSingleWebhook(SQSListenerTest.java:82)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

Comment: If you are looking for an example using spring-cloud aws and Testcontainers with LocalStack. Then, take a look at this one https://github.com/eddumelendez/testcontainers-localstack/tree/main/sqs which uses the latest versions